# Set next boot to kernel

Tags: grub2, kernel

I'm trying to automate a way to set the next boot to be the stock ubuntu kernel. Using a script called `list_kernels.sh` which I found on stackoverflow, I can get the number of the menu including the submenu. However, when I run `grub-reboot *number*` I get the following:

```
root@prod150:~# /tmp/list_kernels.sh 
0: Ubuntu
  0>0 Ubuntu, with Linux 4.9.24
  0>1 Ubuntu, with Linux 4.9.24 (recovery mode)
  0>2 Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-81-generic
  0>3 Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-81-generic (recovery mode)
1: Advanced options for Ubuntu
2: Memory test (memtest86+)
3: Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)




root@prod150:~# grub-reboot 0>2

Menu entry not specified.
Usage: grub-reboot [OPTION] MENU_ENTRY
Set the default boot menu entry for GRUB, for the next boot only.
  -h, --help              print this message and exit
  -v, --version           print the version information and exit
  --boot-directory=DIR    expect GRUB images under the directory DIR/grub
                          instead of the /boot/grub directory

MENU_ENTRY is a number, a menu item title or a menu item identifier. Please note that menu items in
submenus or sub-submenus require specifying the submenu components and then the
menu item component. The titles should be separated using the greater-than
character (>) with no extra spaces. Depending on your shell some characters including > may need escaping. More information about this is available
in the GRUB Manual in the section about the 'default' command. 

Report bugs to <bug-grub@gnu.org>.
```

Does anyone happen to know what's happening? Stackoverflow suggestion online suggest it should work.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: The key phrase appears to be *"Depending on your shell some characters including > may need escaping."* so try `grub-reboot 0\>2` or `grub-reboot 0'>'2` or `grub-reboot '0>2'`

Comment: YES! Thank you so much!